# In Visual Studio 2022, the `#IF DEBUG` pre-compiler constant is True when publishing. How can I fix this?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I am using VB.NET and trying to publish to a directory. However, when I hit "Publish Now", I have code that only runs when `#IF DEBUG` is True. On Visual Studio, when I switch to Release mode and build, the code doesn't run. How do I set it so on publish, it uses Release mode and not Debug mode?

I verified Release mode does not have `DEBUG` constant checked and running Release mode locally is working correctly. Only on "Publish Now" does it use `DEBUG` mode.

Screenshot showing DEBUG constant is disabled in Release config.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what `Publish Now` means, but does that have a `<project folder>/Properties/PublishProfiles/<profile name>.pubxml` file? I opened that in VS and it allows me to select a Configuration (Release, debug, etc). If that's what you mean, open that publish profile and set it to release instead of debug. If not, please provide more info!

Comment: @Jimi I want to run the `#IF DEBUG` when in debug mode. My issue is when I hit "Publish", the published version is still stuck in debug mode, not release. Publish should be publishing the release mode. I know this is happening because my code in '#IF DEBUG' is running when published.

Comment: @ps2goat My project does not have a Properties folder. It is an older VB.NET application. I am right-clicking my project in "Solutions Explorer" and then clicking "Publish" and "Publish Now".

Comment: What kind of project is it? E.g., console app, asp.net app (what type of asp.net), etc.

Comment: [Step 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/publishing-with-visual-studio?pivots=dotnet-8-0#publish-the-app), it is not automatic.

Comment: Yes, sorry, what you were saying wasn't that clear. It looks like you have a .NET Framework application, so you're generating a ClickOnce installation that uses the current Profile. If you build, e.g., a .NET 8 Application, the Publish wizard is aware that you might want to publish a Release build, so it pre-selects this mode, and lets you change it in case you actually want to publish a Debug build. If you want to deploy to a Folder, and not use ClickOnce, change your target .NET version

Comment: Have you changed the build configuration to Release before using Publish Now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you modify the configuration of the Release Mode in Project Property Compile page, you will also need to select the solution configured as **Release** and then publish.

[image]